# Разместить изображение в контейнере который меньше по размеру без деформации

Tags: html, css

Предположим что у меня есть родительский контейнер  с размерами 300px*300px. Внутри него размещается изображение с размерами 300px*500px. Задача разместить изображение таким образом, чтобы оно не изменило размеры, а отцентрировалось и часть верха и низа его скрылось. Задача вроде тривиальная, но решения пока не нашел.

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O0alPmS.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gebq71mr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img"><img src="http://www.xrest.ru/schemes/00/03/bb/62/%D0%97%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-1.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно и без дополнительного контейнера: https://codepen.io/shugich/pen/zwJxyg